# help with translating と

Tags: grammar, translation, syntax, sentence

友人主婦がディズニーランドに行った際、五歳になる長男がトイレに入ったきり姿を消した。スタッフに迷子になった場所を伝えると顔色が変わり「誘拐の可能性がある」**と**すぐにすべての出口でチェックが行なわれた。

I'm translating a news article for my thesis. It's about a wellknown urban legend, the Attempted Abduction. I don't quite understand the use of と in the second sentence... Is it used to make a list of actions? But that would be an unusual use of the particle... Or is it used for reporting speech? But again, there is no verb like say or tell or something... Please help me :)

Comment: I'm assuming you mean the と I made bold. Verbs like 言う, 思う etc are often omitted when the meaning is clear. There are several questions about this on this site.

Comment: ^ although after looking for 5 minutes I've failed miserably to find them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are two と in that sentence. the first means "when" and the second it quotative.